# Does the iPad 2 HDMI out adapter work with the new iPad?

Tags: ipad, hardware, hdmi

I was at the Apple store yesterday and I wanted to purchase an HDMI out adapter for my new iPad. Oe of the employees said to wait becaus they're getting in newer ones for the new iPad, which should handle the retina display better.

Is it really true that the adapter an make a difference? Isn't HDMI going to be HDMI? Does the iPad 2 HDMI out adapter work with the new iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [comments on the new adapter on Apple's online store](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MD098ZM/A?pqid=QPYUHJJXUK2UJDKHUTXYCDKYH7YUHTAPYKTTJHFAK27FT97KP), the iPad 2 HDMI adapter is not fully supported with the new iPad:

> #### Is this a new HDMI AV Adapter ?
>
> It is exactly a new product with the compatibility for the new iPad.
>
> If you try to use the previous adapter on the new iPad it will tell you "This accessory is not supported"

My guess is that the new screen resolution of the new iPad has led to this incompatibility. Besides, with the old adapter the best you could get was 720p, with the new one it's boosted to 1080p.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this question and tried it out. My adapter works flawlessly like it used to with the iPad 2. The only thing I can think about would be "better" compatibility with the new retina resolution. "Better" in terms of, it will scale down better since the new resolution is higher than the one on my tv ^^.

Comment: Does it output 1080p, or 720p like it did with the iPad 2?

Comment: That's a good & a tough question since I'm at the office. I actually didn't check that. I'll check it when I reach home.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, yes. The adapter does work with the new iPad as the cable is described on [the Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE):

[image]

About the second part of your question, the only think I can think of Mirroring. It's obvious a retina screen can mirror more details to a screen then an regular one. But I guess the Apple Store employee is more informed then I am, so I would go with his answer.

Comment: Careful, that's a *new* adapter. Look at the question section.